# How to set options for Boostrap's affix via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I'm trying to get a sub-navbar to affix to the side. Bootstrap's documentation says `Options can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript.` The example they provide is `$('#navbar').affix()`, but how do you pass offset options via javascript? (say 200px offset from top)?

LINK: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix

Comment: And the documentation says it right there - use `$("#navbar").affix({ offset: { top: 200 } });`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#navbar').affix({ offset: { top : 200 } });
```

Comment: `If a single number is provided, the offset will be applied in both top and left directions.` - That will also offset it to the left